# Get Checkbox id of material-ui checkbox by getting the object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to get the object of a Checkbox and extract the id from it.
My markup code :

```
<div style={{display: 'inline-block', }}><Checkbox id='q1' onclick={toggleField(this)}/></div>
<div style={{display: 'inline-block', }}><Checkbox id='q2' onCheck={toggleField(this)}/></div>
```

The function :

```
 toggleField = (obj) => {
    console.log("id : " + obj.id);
  }
```

Aaaannnd this gives me error. It says `toggleField is not defined`.
I am trying to get `q1` or `q2` when they are checked.

I prepared a similar demonstration in basic html and js to test my logic. The markup code

```
<input id='c1' type='checkbox' onclick='handleClick(this);'>Check Me</label>
```

The js code

```
handleClick = (cb) => {
  console.log("Clicked, new value = " + cb.id);
}
```

And it gives me `c1` which is i am trying to get.

How can i achieve the same result for the jsx?

Comment: Solved : console.log(obj.target.id);

Answer (score 0):

In JSX its onClick. Of course it would be nice to add a bind in your constructor like: this.toggleField = this.toggleField.bind(this)

You will get the toggleField(event) and on the event try the target like event.target to reach your id from there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. But could you be a little bit more specific? i am kind of new to js.

Comment: It is highly likely you do not need the id in react at all, but rather the value.
To get the value of any and know which it is it should be the ID, but:
<div style={{display: 'inline-block', }}><Checkbox id='q1' onClick={toggleField.bind(this)}/></div>
and in toggleField:
toggleField(event){
console.log(event.target.id, event.target.value);
}
Hope this solves it for you for now.

Comment: You want to track stuff in the state of the component, and then later do something with the values. SO instead of asisgning ID's to your inputs, assign values to your state directly

Comment: i tried the code and its still giving me the same error "toggleField is not defined". My code : onClick={toggleField.bind(this)} and toggleField = (obj) => {console.log(obj.target.id);}

Comment: Paste all of your code in the question and I will paste you the answer to it.